# Unable to pair Apple wireless keyboard A1314 with macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, monterey

#### Expected

[Pair Apple wireless keyboard A1314 (With batteries)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard) to a MacBook pro running Monterey v12.5.1.

#### Observed

The Apple wireless keyboard cannot connect.

**Errors**

- System Preferences UI: After finding the keyboard and typing the 6 numbers in the error appears, *The pairing attempt was unsuccessful. Click to "Continue" to try again*.
- [blueutil](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430236/304630): *Status: 31 Failed to pair "*{Insert address XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX}*" with error 0x1f (Unspecified Error)*

#### Attempted solutions

- Remove other Bluetooth devices
- [Disconnect the keyboard manually](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237806/304630)
- Disable

  - Wi-Fi
  - VPN
  - Anti-malware
- Check and switch keyboard batteries
- Reset NVRAM and SMC
- Connect via the terminal with [*blueutil*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430236/304630).
- Review [Apple wireless keyboard A1314 manual](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1208/en_US/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard_2009_UG.pdf)

#### Configuration

- Keyboard: Apple wireless keyboard A1314 (With batteries)
- Computer: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)
- Operating system: macOS Monterey v12.5.1
- Computer's bluetooth: 5.0 wireless technology

Comment: Same issue, Monterey 12.6.2. No fix as yet.

Answer (score 3):

I have an A1314 that wouldn't show up in the pairing window either.
I'm on Ventura, MBP M2.  But I also had the same problem getting it to connect to my ipad Pro (4th gen).

After some tinkering and watching some videos I got my keyboard to pair by doing the following:

- **Turn off the keyboard**. *(This is tricky, because the light doesn't stay on for me when it's actually ON.  I never really know if it's on or not.)*

  - **Click and hold the power button for around three seconds**.  The light will come on then then turn off after about 3 seconds. Once the light goes off, let go of the power button.
- **Wait 1-2 seconds**.  *(unclear if this was required, but I had issues getting the next step to work unless I waited a moment between)*
- **Click and hold the power button for about 10 seconds till light blinks but do not let go of the button!**
- **While the light is blinking try pairing.**

I was able to click the connect button on my computer and start pairing.  I don't believe I needed to hold the button while typing the pair code on the keyboard, but it didn't seem to hurt either.

Once it was paired, it worked normally.

TLDR: holding the button during pairing seemed to work where other instructions did not.

Comment: Followup after a few months.  This solution works, but it doesn't seem to remember it's connection day-to-day.   It's a little hit or miss when it decides to remain connected after sitting idle.  That could just be my keyboard being old....

Answer (score 2):

This keyboard is from around 2008 and the [documentation](https://fccid.io/BCGA1314/User-Manual/User-manual-1179310) I’ve found references Leopard (10.5.7)!  Keep in mind this is BT 2.1 era. It is likely that this keyboard/BT standard is simply no longer supported by these newer Operating Systems.  It’s not unheard of for Apple to simply drop support for obsolete products.

If your Mac connects to other Bluetooth devices, it’s technically working.

Try testing the keyboard with a different computer.  If it works there, then it’s narrowed down to a compatibility between that keyboard and the OS.

What could be the incompatibility?

Based on when it was released, it could be the [Bluetooth encryption method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287013/119271) the keyboard employs is no longer supported. BT 2.1 and this keyboard (A1314; AA batteries, no recharging) were all released roughy around this time so the keyboard may not have the latest BT 2.1 specification that was available at the time. This will take more research to confirm.  If it was an earlier BT spec, it may not be capable of encryption and the new OS might require it making them incompatible.

Comment: I have successfully used my Apple_Wireless_Keyboard_2009 with my Mac Mini M2.